# why send_message doesn't exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
>   exception: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute
>   'send_message'

I'm having a problem I really don't understand. Here's my code:

````
async def sad(ctx):
    await client.send_message(ctx.message.author, 'sad')```

AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999771/discord-py-bot-rewrite-attributeerror-bot-object-has-no-attribute-send-messa/53999799#53999799

Answer (score 0):

Discord.py recently migrated to the rewrite: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
# before
await client.send_message(channel, 'Hello')

# after
await channel.send('Hello')
```

### [More here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#sending-messages)