# Unable to send message on member join (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    await bot.send_message(member, "Welcome !")
```

This is my code. And when I a member join the server, I obtain this :

```
Ignoring exception in on_member_join
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pauls\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/pauls/OneDrive/Bureau/Discord UHC/PandaBot/main.py", line 19, in on_member_join
    await bot.send_message(member, "Welcome !")
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Can someone help me pls ?

Comment: Your code and error do not match up. Error has `await bot.send_message(member, "Welcome !")` which is not present in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when I wrote the question. I change the code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999771/discord-py-bot-rewrite-attributeerror-bot-object-has-no-attribute-send-messa

Comment: Thanks and I'm sorry for this dumb question :/

Comment: Don't worry too much about it, it happens :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py bot rewrite AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send\_message'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999771/discord-py-bot-rewrite-attributeerror-bot-object-has-no-attribute-send-messa)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you, if you want to send direct message to connected user:

```
async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send("Welcome!")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple code which sends a custom message on "system message channel" when someone joins the server! OR if there is no system message channel you need to place the specific channel id in `channel_id_here`

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    try:
        channel = member.guild.system_channel
        await channel.send("welcome {} to {} ".format(str(member.mention),str(member.guild)))
    except:
        channel = member.guild.get_channel(channel_id_here)
        await channel.send("welcome {} to {} ".format(str(member.mention),str(member.guild)))
```

Answer (score -1):

That code has a lot of errors. First, `(member, "Welcome !")` should be `(member + "Welcome !")`. Second, `bot.send_message` is invalid; it should be `bot.send` if you are using the rewrite version, but even then it wouldn’t work, because it won’t know what channel to send it in.

```py
mguild = bot.get_guild(<id>)
if member.guild is not None and member.guild == mguild:
    channel = mguild.get_channel(<id>)
    if channel is not None:
        await channel.send(member + "Welcome!")
```

This would work, just replace the `<id>` placeholder with the IDs you want. Cheers!