# line 13, in on_ready Moji = await client.send_message(Channel,Text) AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'.How fix it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

(Sorry for my English) My bot must give role by reactions on emoji but it doesn't work and sand this error:

```
  line 13, in on_ready
 Moji = await client.send_message(Channel,Text)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

This my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".",intents = discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(discord.__version__)
  
  Channel = client.get_channel(815949348948934716)
  Text= "Выбери свою роль"
  Moji = await client.send_message(Channel,Text)
  await client.add_reaction(Moji, emoji='')
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  
  Channel = client.get_channel(815949348948934716)
  if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
    return
  if reaction.emoji == "":
    
    Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="PUBG")
    await client.add_roles(user, Role)
    
client.run("My token")
```

Please help me

Comment: did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999771/discord-py-bot-rewrite-attributeerror-bot-object-has-no-attribute-send-messa

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py bot rewrite AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send\_message'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999771/discord-py-bot-rewrite-attributeerror-bot-object-has-no-attribute-send-messa)

Answer (score 1):

You need to simply do `await Channel.send(Text)`.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".",intents = discord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print(discord.__version__)
  
  Channel = client.get_channel(815949348948934716)
  Text= "Выбери свою роль"
  Moji = await Channel.send(Text)
  await Moji.add_reaction('')
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
  
  Channel = client.get_channel(815949348948934716)
  if reaction.message.channel.id != Channel:
    return
  if reaction.emoji == "":
    
    Role = discord.utils.get(user.server.roles, name="PUBG")
    await client.add_roles(user, Role)
    
client.run("My token")
```

Comment: Thanks, it sand message but still not very good.I get new error:```line 13, in on_ready
    await client.add_reaction(Moji, emoji='')
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_reaction' ```

Comment: @HackJonny I've edited my code to fix that. You need to do `await Moji.add_reaction('')`. Also, make sure to mark my answer as correct by clicking the check button below the downvote button next to my post.

Comment: Okay, it sand message with emoji but still doesn't give role, but it doesn't sand error. Please help 

Comment: I checked your answer and it doesn't work. It sand message with reaction but when I react to emoji, it doesn't give role